# Is Karma server a singleton?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I am getting really weird behavior from the karma test runner, and I don't know why. As best as I can tell, the new Server() option isn't actually instanciating a new server, but is some how a singleton? I put the ? because that doesn't make sense to have a construnctor return a singleton... so confused.

```
"use strict";

var Server = require('karma').Server;
var runner = require('karma').runner;

var filePath = process.cwd();
filePath += "/karma.conf.js";

//files needs to be an array of string file matchers
function runTests(files, port) {
    var config = {
        configFile: filePath,
        files: files,
        port: port
    };
    var server = new Server(config, function(exitCode) {
        console.log('Karma has server exited with ' + exitCode);
        process.exit(exitCode)
    });

    server.on('run_complete', function (browser, result) {
        console.log('A browser run was completed');
        console.log(result);
    });

    server.on('browsers_ready', function () {
        runner.run({port: port}, function(exitCode) {
             console.log('Karma runner.run has exited with ' + exitCode);
             process.exit(exitCode)
         });
    });

    server.start();
}

runTests(['test/**/*Spec.js', 'tmp/example.js'], 9876);
runTests(['test/**/*Spec.js', 'tmp/example2.js'], 9877);
runTests(['test/**/*Spec.js', 'tmp/example3.js'], 9878);
```

The output I get is :

```
A browser run was completed
{ success: 1,
  failed: 0,
  error: false,
  disconnected: false,
  exitCode: 0 }
A browser run was completed
{ success: 0,
  failed: 1,
  error: true,
  disconnected: false,
  exitCode: 1 }
A browser run was completed
{ success: 0,
 failed: 1,
  error: true,
  disconnected: false,
  exitCode: 1 }
Karma runner.run has exited with 0
```

As you can see, the server never exits (why, i don't know), and the runner only exits once, why? I still can't say... The expected behavior was that three karma server instances would be created, and they would fire .on(browser_ready in no particular order. This in turn would cause the runner to tell the server at that port to run (3 separate times). Then, when the run is complete, it would exit the runner (3 times not once) printing the results to the terminal, and at some point exit the server (3 times not 0).

Comment: Is it possible, that the `.on` method was fired 3 times, and then all 3 servers were terminated without firing the exit method of the runner?

Comment: It is definitely possible Jamie, but I am at a loss then as to why the exit callback wasn't fired, or why the runner callback was called exactly once

Comment: It is possible that Karma **terminated** the process.

Comment: So I ran it with log level debug, and there is no debug logging that says that karma terminated it.